# Merge duplicate rows with same values across two columns in my mysql table and add the values in third column

Tags: mysql, duplicates, rows, qlikview

I have a data  table with 3 columns like below:

```
Item1  Item2  Value
Apple   Orange  3
Apple  Banana  2
Mango  Apple  2
Banana  Apple  6
Apple   Mango   5
Orange  Banana   4
Orange   Apple   5
```

I want to remove the duplicate rows based on the combinations of two columns Item1 & Item2 and show only one in any order and want to add their values as a result, so as the final output in my table box  can be:

```
Item1   Item2   Value
Apple   Orange   8
Apple   Banana   8
Mango   Apple   7
Orange   Banana   4
```

Thank you for any help or attention !  or at least  can any one  answer me if its even possible to do that !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `LEAST/GREATEST` trick here:

```sql
SELECT LEAST(Item1, Item2) AS Item1,
       GREATEST(Item1, Item2) AS Item2,
       SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

| Item1 | Item2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Orange | 8 |
| Apple | Banana | 8 |
| Apple | Mango | 7 |
| Banana | Orange | 4 |

### Demo

Comment: You made my day , thank you for your it works perfectly